# How can I print a number into a char array?

Tags: c

I'm developing a pacman game with allegro (in Ubuntu) but I am unable to show the score. I found this code but it doesn't work. Could you help me please?

```
char scoretxt[10];
printf(scoretxt,"score: %d",score);
textout_ex(buffer, font, scoretxt, TILE_SIZE*(MAP_WIDTH)*3/4, TILE_SIZE, makecol(255,255,255), makecol(0,0,0));
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be using `snprintf`, not `printf`:

```
snprintf(scoretxt, 10, "score: %d", score);
```

Here the `10` is the length of the buffer `scoretxt` to ensure that `snprintf` doesn't write outside the allocated array.

Comment: @EvanTeran: As far as I can tell, it does.

Comment: you are correct, I read the original as `sprintf` not `printf`. My bad, adding +1 for correct answer :-P